# bindActionCreators called on a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was under the impression that the purpose of `bindActionCreators` was to wrap `actionCreators` in a dispatch function, and give these new functions a name (which could be passed to components as props, via `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect`).

However, a tutorial I found seemed to call `bindActionCreators` on a dispatch function (`updatePerson`), which seems to violate the whole point of `bindActionCreators`.

> actions/update_person.js

```
import { UPDATE_PERSON } from './types';

export default function updatePerson(person) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(updatePersonAsync(person));
  }
}

function updatePersonAsync(person){
  return {
    type: UPDATE_PERSON,
    payload: person
  };
}
```

> components/WantedCard.js

```
//connects redux actions to props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updatePerson: updatePerson,
    deletePerson: deletePerson
  }, dispatch);
}
```

What exactly am I getting wrong here, with my understanding? UpdatePerson is already bound(?)

This is the tutorial repo: https://github.com/lorenseanstewart/redux-wanted-list and blog post https://lorenstewart.me/2016/11/27/a-practical-guide-to-redux/

Answer (score 1):

> UpdatePerson is already bound(?)

No it wasn't it's just a normal function that you `import`.
In order to make it play with the `redux` flow cycle you need to `dispatch` this function.

When you are not passing `mapDispatchToProps` you get the `dispatch` function as a prop to your connected component, so to use it you would have to do it like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(updatePerson())
```

If you do decide to pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect` then you will not receive `dispatch` as a prop but you could wrap your actions with it:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updatePerson: () => {
      dispatch(updatePerson())
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can just pass an object:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    updatePerson,
    deletePerson
}
```

Another way is to use `bindActionCreators` (like you mentioned in your post)
With this approach you can dispatch the action with this line of code:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updatePerson: updatePerson,
    deletePerson: deletePerson
  }, dispatch);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
this.props.updatePerson()
```

Note that you can use the [Shorthand property names of ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) if the key matches the variable

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updatePerson,
    deletePerson
  }, dispatch);
}
```

Another nice approach with `bindActionCreators` is to import all actions as alias (even different actions from different files):

```
import * as userActions from '../url'; 
import * as otherActions from '../otherUrl';
```

And then stack them all in one object (or separate them if you want):

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    const combinedActions = { ...userActions, ...otherActions };
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(combinedActions, dispatch)
    };
}
```

Now you can refer any action via the `actions` object:

```
this.props.actions.myAction();
this.props.actions.myOtherAction();
```

You can read me about the various options in the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)

Comment: But you should be able to dispatch actions with that code without needing a dispatch call in the actionCreator itself (since bindActionCreators is 'adding' dispatch to them) (?)

Comment: an action creator is just a plain function that returns an action(`object`). without dispatching it, you will just get back the object it is returning. when using `dispatch` you let it "play" in the `redux` flow and thus `reducers` or `middlewares` can catch them when they are invoked.